# Windows API CodePack. Get all selected items in the CommonOpenFileDialog:IFileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, windows-api-code-pack

I work with the CommonOpenFileDialog class from the Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework that implements the IFileOpenDialog interface.

More info about Windows API CodePack here:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

**Problem:**
The below method returns the **First selected folder** if (multiple folders) or (mutltiple folders and files) were selected in the "Open File Dialog" dialog window.

```
IFileOpenDialog.GetSelectedItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellItemArray ppsai)
```

How to return **All selected elements** (folders and files) in the IFileOpenDialog window as a list of IShellItem, no matter what I selected there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the **Multiselect** property.

Here's an unmarshalled example:

```
CommonOpenFileDialog folderDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog("Input Folder Selection");
        folderDialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
        folderDialog.Multiselect = true;

        if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            foreach (string folderName in folderDialog.FileNames)   //it's a little confusing, but FileNames represents folders as well in the API
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```